Identifying and retrieving particular sequences of characters from within text fields containing Basic Data desc
I have a list named MAT_DESC that contains material descriptions in a free-text format. Here are some sample values from the MAT_DESC column:
QWERTYUI PN-DR, Coarse, TR, 1-1/2 in, 50/Carton, 200 ea/Case, Dispenser Pack  
2841 PC GREY AS/AF (20/CASE)
CI-1A, up to 35 kV, Compact/Solid, Stranded, 10/Case 
MT53H7A4410WS5 WS WEREDSS PMR45678 ERTYUI HEERTYUIND 10/case 
TYPE.2 86421-K40-F000, 1 Set/Pack, 100 Packs/Case
Clear, 1 in x 36 yd, 4.8 mil, 24 rolls per case  
3M™ Victory Series™ Bracket MBT™ 017-873, .022, UL3, 0T/8A, Hk, 5/Pack 
3M™ BX™ Dual Reader Protective Eyewear 11458-00000-20, Clear Anti-Fog Lens, Silver/Black Frame, +2.0 Top/Bottom Diopter, 20 ea/Case
4220VDS-QCSHC/900-000/A CABINET EMPTY
3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Product SJ5476 Fluorescent Yellow, 3.000/Case 
3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Products SJ61A2 Black, 10,000/Case




Material Desc
String to be Extracted




QWERTYUI PN-DR, Coarse, TR, 1-1/2 in, 50/Carton, 200 ea/Case, Dispenser Pack
50/Carton, 200 ea/Case


2841 PC GREY AS/AF (20/CASE)
20/CASE


TYPE.2 86421-K40-F000, 1 Set/Pack, 100 Packs/Case
1 Set/Pack, 100 Packs/Case


RTYU 31655, 240+, 6 in, 50 Discs/Roll, 6 Rolls/Case
50 Discs/Roll, 6 Rolls/Case


Clear, 1 in x 36 yd, 4.8 mil, 24 rolls per case
24 rolls per case


3M™ Victory Series™ Bracket MBT™ 017-873, .022, UL3, 0T/8A, Hk, 5/Pack
5/Pack


3M™ BX™ Dual Reader Protective Eyewear 11458-00000-20, Clear Anti-Fog Lens, Silver/Black Frame, +2.0 Top/Bottom Diopter, 20 ea/Case
20 ea/Case


4220VDS-QCSHC/900-000/A CABINET EMPTY
No units


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Product SJ5476 Fluorescent Yellow, 3.000/Case
3.000/Case


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Products SJ61A2 Black, 10,000/Case
10,000/Case



I'm trying to extract specific patterns of substrings from the MAT_DESC column, such as the quantity and unit information (e.g., "50 Discs/Roll", "200 ea/Case", "10/Case",50/Carton, 200 ea/Case etc.).
I'm currently using the following PYTHON to attempt this:
pattern = r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)/(\w+)"

results = []

for desc in material_descriptions:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, desc)
    unit_strings = []
    if matches:
        for match in matches:
            quantity, unit1, unit2 = match
            unit_string = f"{quantity} {unit1}/{unit2}"
            unit_strings.append(unit_string)
    if unit_strings:
        unit_info = ", ".join(unit_strings)
        results.append((desc, unit_info))

for material_desc, unit_info in results:
    print(f"Material Description: {material_desc}")
    print(f"Unit Information: {unit_info}")
    print()

Python script fails in the below listed scenarios



Material Desc
String to be Extracted




3M™ Victory Series™ Bracket MBT™ 017-873, .022, UL3, 0T/8A, Hk, 5/Pack
5/Pack


3M™ BX™ Dual Reader Protective Eyewear 11458-00000-20, Clear Anti-Fog Lens, Silver/Black Frame, +2.0 Top/Bottom Diopter, 20 ea/Case
20 ea/Case


4220VDS-QCSHC/900-000/A CABINET EMPTY
No units


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Product SJ5476 Fluorescent Yellow, 3.000/Case
3.000/Case


3M™ Bumpon™ Protective Products SJ61A2 Black, 10,000/Case
10,000/Case



Is there a way to achieve this ?

Try r'\b(?<!\d[,.])(?<!\d-)((?:\d+/)?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\b((\s*\w*/)?\s*(?(3)\w+|\w+\s+per\s+\w+)(?=\s*(?:[,)]|$)))', see the regex demo.

@WiktorStribiżew, thanks for this. I get results like when I try:
Material Description: 3M™ Victory Series™ Bracket MBT™ 017-873, .022, UL3, 0T/8A, Hk, 5/Pack
Unit Information: 5 /Pack/
Material Description: 3M™ BX™ Dual Reader Protective Eyewear 11458-00000-20, Clear Anti-Fog Lens, Silver/Black Frame, +2.0 Top/Bottom Diopter, 20 ea/Case
Unit Information: 20 ea/Case/ ea.  adding extra / and ea in the last example

The groups in my regex that you need are just Group 1 and Group 2, Group 3 is auxiliary. You need to process Group 2 value as per your needs (splitting with / I suppose).

OK, here is a variation: \b(?<!\d[,.])(?<!\d-)((?:\d+/)?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\b(\s*(\w*)/)?\s*((?(2)\w+|\w+\s+per\s+\w+))(?=\s*(?:[,)]|$)) (regex demo),  and in your code, you need something like quantity, _, unit1, unit2 = match

Does it work or is it helpful at all?

@WiktorStribiżew,The solution works for most scenarios. I have 300,000 records, and I also ran the script in SAP Data Services, which has its own limitations. I would say it solved approximately 75% of my problem. Thank you

Well, to solve the 100% of issues, you need to explain in detail all requirements for the pattern, the comprehensive description of what exactly the pattern should match at each location.

For the data you shared, I suggest using
\b(?<!\d[,.])(?<!\d-)((?:\d+/)?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\b(\s*(\w*)/)?\s*((?(2)\w+|\w+\s+per\s+\w+))(?=\s*(?:[,)]|$))

See the regex demo. In your code, since the regex contains 4 groups now, you need to use
quantity, _, unit1, unit2 = match

Just to skip Group 2 value that is technical in this regex.
Regex details:

\b - a word boundary
(?<!\d[,.-]) - immediately before the current location, there should be no digit + ,, . or -
((?:\d+/)?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*) - Group 1: an optional group of one or more digits and then a /, and then one or more digits and then zero or more repetitions of , or - and one or more digits
\b - a word boundary
(\s*(\w*)/)? - Group 2 (optional): zero or more whitespaces and then zero or more word chars (captured into Group 3) and a / char
\s* - zero or more whitespaces
((?(2)\w+|\w+\s+per\s+\w+)) - Group 4: if Group 2 matched, match one or more word chars, else, one or more words + one or more whitepsaces, per + one or more whitepsaces, one or more word chars
(?=\s*(?:[,)]|$)) - a positive lookahead requiring (immediately to the right of the current location) zero or more whitespaces, then a , or ) or end of string.

